# The use of the phrase "RemoveAbandonedClosed" in deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions, auto-delete

I was checking the list of *recently deleted* questions and then I tripped upon [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070562/is-there-a-limit-where-numbers-get-irrational). This question, however, has nothing to do with whether the question should be closed or reopened; deleted or undeleted.

What I want to ask is, there I saw this snippet:

[image]

I have seen these type of snippets before but earlier they did not have this "(**RemoveAbandonedClosed**)" phrase in that snippet.

What is this phrase meant to do here and what does it mean? Any particular reason that they were not seen earlier? Or perhaps seen earlier, but only in a few specific questions?

Clarification required.

Comment: What was unclear about the explication in the banner? It says "This question was deleted automatically." And directs to [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) for further information. Where it says among other things: "If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
[some technicalities]
... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as RemoveAbandonedClosed.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the details here:

[Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

The gist is that a question closed for 9 days, with a non-positive score, no positively scored or accepted answers is deleted automatically if it hasn't been edited for 9 days.

(Also relevant: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222))